# Showing a custom message in the dropdown (AutoCompleteTextView)?

Tags: android

Android developers,

I want to show a custom message like "Sorry the data you searched for does not exist in the list as of now" when users type in a text irrelevant to the data adapter linked to a ACTV.

Should a custom textwatcher be written or is there a simpler way to handle this?

I am sorry I haven't tried any coding, am just analysing this before going into real coding.

Comment: Where do you want to show this message? Like a Toast, or inside the dropdown?

Comment: Inside the dropdown. Lets say i have a, b, c in adapter. And i type d. Then my suggestion should say 'sorry nothing found'

Comment: So you need to create a custom Adapter to give to the AutoCompleteText. You need to override the getFilter() method and provide a way to filter the result. Inside this filtering process, if no result is detect, simply add a fake one with your message